# Using Skorokhod’s representation theorem to prove a sufficient condition for uniform integrability

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-analysis

Let $X_n,X$ be random variables such that $X_n\xrightarrow{D}X$ and $E(|X_n|)\rightarrow E(|X|)$. Show uniform integrability.

Now I know, that I am supposed to use Skorokhod’s representation theorem to obtain a random variables $Y_n,Y$ on the standard Borel-sigma-algebra of $(0,1)$.
I also know, that it suffices to show uniform integrability for for these $Y_n$ as that only depends on the original Probability measure with density $X_n$ wich is the same as the Lebesgues measure on $(0,1)$ with density $Y_n$. Ideally I would like to find a RV $Z\in\mathcal{L}^1$ such that $|Y_n|\leq Z$. That would imply the wanted result. However I could not find arguments for the existence of such $Z$ as I do not even know if $E(Y_n)<\infty$

Answer (score 1):

**Example:** $X_n=\pm n$ with probability $1/2n$ for each value, and $=0$ with probability $1-1/n$. Then $X_n\stackrel{D}{\to}0$, $E[X_n]=0$ for each $n$, but $E[|X_n|]=1$ for each $n$, so uniform integrability fails.

Is there a hypothesis missing?  For example, should  it be that $X_n\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, the expected value is supposed to converge in absolute value like so:  $E(|X_n|)\rightarrow E(|X|)$. I have edited my question to represent that.

Comment: If $\lim_n E[|X_n|]=E[|X|]$ then   Scheffé's Lemma can be applied to the sequence of non-negative random variables $(|X_n|)$.

Comment: What if $E(X)=\infty$?

Comment: If also $X$ has infinite expectation the $(X_n)$ isn't UI.

Comment: Well that is bad, as I did not get any other conditions the random variables.